# 'str' object has no attribute 'dt'

Tags: python, dataframe

I am converting a pandas dataframe with Timestamps to strings with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'sentencess' : sentencess, 'publishedAts' : publishedAts, 'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens })
    df['publishedAts'] = df['publishedAts'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

But I found error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dt'

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'sentencess' : sentencess, 'publishedAts' : publishedAts, 'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens })
df['publishedAts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAts']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Actually in default, `pd.to_datetime` gives `YYYY-MM-DD`, so if that's okay with you, you could use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'sentencess' : sentencess, 'publishedAts' : publishedAts, 'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens })
df['publishedAts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAts'])
```

Comment: I've used it before. But I got this output : {'Negatif ': {Timestamp('2019-08-25 00:00:00', freq='D'): 2.0, Timestamp('2019-08-26 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3.0, Timestamp('2019-08-27 00:00:00', freq='D'): 5.0, Timestamp('2019-08-28 00:00:00', freq='D'): nan}, 'Netral ': {Timestamp,..... and I need a string not timestamps

Comment: I need to return it to json and keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp